# Sweet alert working only when i'm entering right details but after entering wrong and then right it's showing result for wrong details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Sweet alert is showing status of wrong password if i enter wrong passwords that is correct but then if i make them right it still showing status of wrong passwords not getting what is problem

Php code

```
    if($new_pass_hash != $pass_hash){
      echo"Current password is wrong";
      exit();
}else{

        $updated_pass_hash = sha1($enew.$salt);

        $update_pass = " UPDATE vendor SET pass_hash = '$updated_pass_hash' WHERE vd_id='$vd_id'";

        $run_update = mysqli_query($con, $update_pass);

        echo"Updated";
}
```

Response

```
              $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data: "pass=" +pass + "&enew="+enew+"&repeat="+repeat,
                url:"phpfiles/edit-password.php",
                success: function(data){
                    if(data =='Updated'){
                        swal({   
                        title: 'Success',
                        text: 'Password updated successfully' ,   
                        imageUrl: "icons/thumbs-up.jpg" 
                        },
                        function(){
                             window.location.href = 'docs.php';

                        });
                    }else{
                     swal({   
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'Current password is wrong',
                        type: 'error'
                        });
                    }
                }
            }); 
            return false;
```

Comment: what comes in the ``data`` variable the second time?

Comment: @Alexander M. It should be "Current password is wrong" which would be in else condition and then i'm changing passwords to right but it's still showing results for else condition

Comment: the question was what *comes*, not *should come*

Comment: sorry, when i making them right after inserting wrong in first time, First comes "Updated" but just after also pops up 'Current password is wrong' and password changes as required. But if i insert wrong passwords and then refresh page and then again insert correct passwords it works fine.